# Blank screen when installing on an Acer Aspire 4750Z

Tags: 11.04, installation, acer

I just got a new Acer Aspire 4750Z Laptop

I am trying to install Ubuntu in it.

I downloaded the latest Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit and created a Startup Disk using a USB.

I get to the menu to select whether I want to try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu, but when I select any of these I get a Blank Screen with a still cursor at top left.

- I try with pressing e to edit parameters from menu. Enter `set acpi=off` and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to Boot. No Result.

Comment: I had similar problem with my HP laptop. In my case it was an ACPI related issue, please, try to boot appending `acpi=off` to kernel parameters list. I don't exactly remember how I did that, but I'm sure it's possible (I was able to do that using the live CD, probably there is an Advance boot options menu or something like that). HTH

Comment: @Guandalino I try with pressing e to edit parameters from menu.

Enter 'set acpi=off' and press F10 to Boot. No Result.

Comment: IIRC you have to append `acpi=off` after the word `splash`, using a space as separator. The line you have to change should be something like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`.

Comment: Seems you are talking about the grub file. How do I edit a file when its not even installed. I don't have any files in my machine.

Comment: Please, for an explanation read [Changing the CD's Default Boot Options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing%20the%20CD%27s%20Default%20Boot%20Options) on Ubuntu Community Documentation. **Disclaimer**: That article is incomplete, and needs to be expanded, and maybe it doesn't exactly reflect a valid procedure for Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try to burn your CD or USB stick again with Ubuntu 11.04's boot creator. Do not make your 1104 installing media under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the kind of error  you get if you have a bad stick of RAM in your computer.  Run MEMTEST86 (on the live boot cd for Ubuntu)  and run it for about 3+ hours.  See if you get any errors.   Also, could be "video memory" ?   Keep in mind: some laptops have video memory sharing with the RAM.